# Ruby rspec realtime output

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have been using `rspec` for some time now, and I have noticed that I do not get realtime output to STDOUT, that is console hangs until all test are done and then I get results.

I happen to find this rspec formatter (really cool) https://github.com/mattsears/nyan-cat-formatter and realized that all this time I have been missing out on realtime STDOUT output.

I have tried setting `STDOUT.sync = true` at the beginning of my test execution but no cigar :(

I am using `Ubuntu 12.04 | Ruby 1.9.3`

Answer (score 0):

I use [Fuubar](https://github.com/jeffkreeftmeijer/fuubar), "an instafailing RSpec formatter that uses a progress bar instead of a string of letters and dots as feedback" for pretty much all my projects now as I think it provides a meaningful progress bar, as well as realtime feedback.

Although it's not as fun as Nyancat, it's certainly a lot faster!